# How I change my compiler from BABEL to SWC in NextJS version 12.1.0

Tags: next.js

Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled

I am facing above info at my project terminal . I want convert my NextJS project compiler from babel to SWC . I saw guides from google but I am failed . I need step by step guide.

This is my current babelrc [image: .babelrc]

This is my next.config.js [image: next.config.js]
This is my terminal
[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXm9D.png)

Comment: Removing the `.babelrc` file will enable SWC by default.

Comment: I tried removing .babelrc but after that project is not running

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are using a Babel plugin for something that can be done through Next.js config: inlining the SVG.

You can remove the `.babelrc` config and use something like [next-images](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-images) that will handle for you the import of the SVG in your app.

Comment: How I check my SWC compiler working or not ? or Babel working ?

Comment: If you are working with Next.js v12 and you removed the Babel configuration,  SWC is running for you right now.

Comment: I am not understand the meaning of babel configuration ?? brief explain me please

Comment: You just don't need the Babel configuration if you use `next-images`. Anyway the configuration you pasted above is related to the (old) next/babel plugin + a plugin to inline the SVG for you when you `import svg from './some-image.svg'`